# How can Google.com have itself as Authoritative Name Server in its DNS?

Tags: dns, nameservers, tld

There must be something wrong with my understanding of DNS and since I might not be the only one I would like to ask this here for clarification.

If I make a whois on **google.com** I realize that its name servers are:

```
Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
```

At this point I am confused because these DNS depend on the domain itself.

And if I do

```
    dig google.com @ns1.google.com
or: dig ns1.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

The response does show **aa** flags proving that ns1.google.com is indeed the Authoritative server for everything about google.com.

How is this possible? This seems to me like the chicken and egg problem.

If I want to know the NS servers of **google.com** I ask a root server for the .com TLD, correct? It tells me that **ns1.google.com** is that NS server. Now I need to resolve **ns1.google.com** but it depends on the domain that I was trying to resolve in the first place... so I'm stuck in a loop!

The only explanation I can think of is that the root server hosts a zone for **google.com** and is therefore able to return an IP for **ns1.google.com**. But what is this service that allows us (or only big players?) to have some zone hosted by the root servers? (I'm probably assuming wrong here but I can't see another explanation)

I noticed **pinterest.com** is set up the same way.

Comment: You already find out those are glud records involved (but your question is offtopic). You can easily see them if you query the parent authoritative nameservers: `dig ns1.google.com A @a.gtld-servers.net`. For anyone thinking about using this setup: yes it works, it can have merit in some cases, but it also have drawbacks. It is better not to do that until you understand the DNS well.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, someone on Freenode gave me the keyword I needed: **GLUE RECORDS** (which is not a music label).

A very good explanation is provided here: https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record